# How to convert a shared library into static library in Linux

Tags: c++, c, linux

I have Class `xxx.cpp` which can be converted to a static library instead of creating a shared object to improve the performance of the system. Hence please provide the steps to convert it from `.so` to `.a`.

Comment: If you have the source, can't you just compile it as a static library?

Comment: There is no "converter" from *shared* to *static* libraries. They are different ways of *compiling* a library. A *static* library is created with e.g. `ar -cvq foobar.a foo.o bar.o`. A shared library is created via `gcc -shared ...`. The steps to covert is simply to recompile as a static lib.

Answer (score 1):

No `conversion` is required here since you have the source file `xxx.cpp`

You may

1. **Create the library first**

   ```
   g++ -static -c xxx.cpp -o xxx.o # use g++ instead of gcc
   ar -rcs libxxx.a xxx.o
   ```
2. **Link to the library like below**

   ```
   g++ -static somefile.cpp -o somefile.elf -L/path/to/libxxx.a -lxxx
   ```